# YOGA710 - UBUNTU 16.04 - Touch Screen not working!

Tags: 16.04, lenovo, touchscreen

I just recieved my new yoga 710.
Everthing seems to work fine, except the touch screen.
I didn't found any solution that work for me in the forum. Does anybody got any solution?

*I installed fresh UBUNTU 16.04 on my machine.

tnx!

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the touch screen drivers for the Yoga 710 threw the terminal  , sometimes is just that or move to Ubuntu 17.04 (it has more compatibility in drivers ) and update the computer drivers and software .

That might solved your problem mine got fix thanks to that .

Comment: how do I download touch screen drivers threw the terminal?

Comment: An answer, Somebody?

Answer (score 0):

Find it you need to go to this link it will help you to download the drivers and fix any kind of bugs etc .

[How to Install Linux Kernel 4.7 in Ubuntu 16.04/14.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/07/install-linux-kernel-4-7-ubuntu-16-04/)